# Handling CSV response from semrush to JSON using python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I am using semrush to get the response of the analysis of the website. What I received is CSV kind of data and after reviewing the documentation I could not get the factor by which I can get the `json` response from the SEMRUSH

Here is the code and respective response:

```
>>> data = requests.get('http://api.semrush.com/?key=KEY&type=domain_ranks&domain=example.com')
>>> data.text
u'Date;Database;Domain;Rank;Organic Keywords;Organic Traffic;Organic Cost;Adwords Keywords;Adwords Traffic;Adwords Cost;PLA keywords;PLA uniques\r\n20171108;ae;exmaple.com;34;3013;690144;700580;0;0;0;0;0\r\n20171108;af;example.com;88;663;17056;2868;0;0;0;0;0\r\n
```

I am looking to get a response in json like this:

```
{
'Date':'20171108',
'Domain':'example.com',
'Database': ['ae','af']
'ae':[
'Organic Keywords': 34,
'Organic Traffic': 3013
'Organic Cost':690144,
'Adwords Keywords':700580,
'Adwords Traffic':0,
'Adwords Cost':0,
'PLA keywords':0,
'PLA uniques':0


],
'af':[
'Rank':
'Organic Keywords':88,
'Organic Traffic':663,
'Organic Cost':17056,
'Adwords Keywords':
'Adwords Traffic':0,
'Adwords Cost':0,
'PLA keywords':0,
'PLA uniques':0


]
}
```

Kindly, let me know what to improve inorder to have the above result.

Comment: I think you should convert data manually. `csv` format allows to tie many values with `item`(column - values). it's a simple format(line breaks + delimiter). `json` format assumes that 1 key can store different values(str, int, list of dicts, dicts of lists etc.). These are different things and I think that there is no instrument for transformation, because every case is very specific(as in your example).

Comment: Have you tried Semrush API ever? Just to know whether you have tried one example, because the data what is getting delivered is always in the same format. But the point how to to get into json format so that I can visualize?

Comment: I didn't try. Try to add next headers to `request`: `{'Content-Type': 'application/json',  'Accept': 'application/json'}`. Note: I do not know anything about Semrush API(it's just a thought)

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I already have checked that. I would like to know whether you have checked it with the semrush api as I guess it doesn't support json at all. Otherwise semrush would have given an endpoint for the json response.

Comment: I didn't check. But I read little bit docs and also didn't see anything about `json` (((

Comment: @DanilaGanchar  Yes that's why I am looking or a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using these lines of code to do it:

```
d1 = dict(zip(data.text.splitlines()[0].split(';'),data.text.splitlines()[1].split(';')))
d1['Database'] = [d1['Database'],text.splitlines()[2].split(';')[1]]
d1[d1['Database'][0]] = dict(list(d1.items())[3:])
d2 = dict(zip(text.splitlines()[0].split(';'),text.splitlines()[2].split(';')))
d1[d1['Database'][1]] = dict(list(d2.items())[3:])
for i in list(d1.keys())[3:-2]:
    d1.pop(i)
print(d1)
```

Now the output will be:

```
{'Date': '20171108', 'Database': ['ae', 'af'], 'Domain': 'exmaple.com', 'ae': {'Rank': '34', 'Organic Keywords': '3013', 'Organic Traffic': '690144', 'Organic Cost': '700580', 'Adwords Keywords': '0', 'Adwords Traffic': '0', 'Adwords Cost': '0', 'PLA keywords': '0', 'PLA uniques': '0'}, 'af': {'Rank': '88', 'Organic Keywords': '663', 'Organic Traffic': '17056', 'Organic Cost': '2868', 'Adwords Keywords': '0', 'Adwords Traffic': '0', 'Adwords Cost': '0', 'PLA keywords': '0', 'PLA uniques': '0'}}
```

To print it nicer :-)

```
pprint(d1)
```

Will result in:

```
{'Database': ['ae', 'af'],
 'Date': '20171108',
 'Domain': 'exmaple.com',
 'ae': {'Adwords Cost': '0',
        'Adwords Keywords': '0',
        'Adwords Traffic': '0',
        'Organic Cost': '700580',
        'Organic Keywords': '3013',
        'Organic Traffic': '690144',
        'PLA keywords': '0',
        'PLA uniques': '0',
        'Rank': '34'},
 'af': {'Adwords Cost': '0',
        'Adwords Keywords': '0',
        'Adwords Traffic': '0',
        'Organic Cost': '2868',
        'Organic Keywords': '663',
        'Organic Traffic': '17056',
        'PLA keywords': '0',
        'PLA uniques': '0',
        'Rank': '88'}}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @JafferWilson Your welcome, happy to answer one of your old questions :-), I usually woudn't do this big answer, but with you, yes :-)